# Problem with duy z-room reverb in pro tools 10

Tags: pro-tools, plug-ins

Hey guys,

I've just moved to PT10 on macbook pro, mountain lion and I have a problem with this plugin. Always when I run pt this plugin gets an error during initial start up, message box pops out saying sth like: "this plugin can't be loaded propably because of registration issue" Do you know what's the problem?

best!
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

You haven't registered it?

See:
http://www.duystore.com/com/register.html
or
http://www.duy.com/webstuff/contact.html

Comment: Oh!!!! I tought it's something else! Thanks man! it propably will help!

Comment: uhm, but this plugin isn't there... (it's that free reverb plugin).

Comment: Well in that case you probably missed some information regarding how to register it, when you downloaded the plug-in.